Router is not working in android (angular 18 with capacitor)
I build applications in angular 18 and use capacitor to generate APK. I am not using ionic.
this simple application has 2 components
listing and detail. The application is working fine with routing in web.
The issue is when I use the capacitor and build the Android app, routing is not working.
listing HTML
<div class="node"
    [ngClass]="ind.color"
    [style]="{ top: ind.top, left: ind.left }"
    (click)="showDetail(ind.id)">
<div class="name">{{ ind.name }}</div>
    <div class="handle">{{ ind.handle }}</div></div>

listing component.ts
showDetail(id: number):void {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', 1]);}

routing.ts
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: DetailComponent
  }

capacitor config
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.am.app',
  appName: 'Project01',
  webDir: 'dist/project01/browser',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  server: {
    url: ' http://192.168.1.7:4200/',
    cleartext: true,
  },
  plugins: {
    CapacitorHttp: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
};

Where I did wrong, it's really long day for me :/
Edited
I find the (click) function is not working in the android emulator.that causing the issue. any solution

Check your capacitor configurations file and ensure that "webDir" is pointing to built path (which is most probably "www").
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.company.appname',
  appName: 'My Capacitor App',
  webDir: 'www',
};

reference: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config
Also, check android configuration is correct or not from below official documentation:
reference: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/configuration
If you can provide more details about issue then we can discuss further about how to fix it.
**Edited: **
Debug your click event through chrome://inspect on your chrome browser:
showDetail(id: number) {
    console.log('Clicked ID:', id); // Add this line
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', id]);
}

To verify that it is working or not. Also, check if there is any console errors or not which can help to debug further.

I have updated the capacitor config. Also, add the Stackblitz project for better understand. Check my updated question.
